# ArcGIS Operations Dashboard: Is there a way to create a widget which counts the occurrence of a text attribute?

Tags: arcgis-online, fields-attributes, filter, operations-dashboard

I am using Operations Dashboard of ArcGIS and I would like to add a widget which count the occurrence of a text value "DAMAGED" in a field ("STATE"). I only found the way to access numeric attributes, but not text ones. I also tried with the widget "Interrogation" (I hope the traduction is right), but I am supposed to start an operation to find the desired number. Rather, I'd like to have a number showing wothout any action. I thought using a filter on that field would do the trick, but this seems only possible for numeric data as I said.

As my field "STATE" can only have two values ("WORKING" or "DAMAGED"), I am aware I can change to a numeric type of field (1 or 0), but this solution would not be as descriptive as the text way, and I would prefer not to change it. Does anyone know how to do this with the "standard" Operations Dashboard (not entering the "developer side")?

To give an overview of what I am doing: I created a point feature representing the public lights of a city (data are invented); I added the field "STATE" which has a domain to only allow the choice between the two attributes "WORKING" and "DAMAGED"; I published the feature to AGOL as feature service. At the end I would like to change the attribute of some lights from "WORKING" to "DAMAGED" with Collector, and see a sort of warming (a count actually) using a widget in Operations Dashboard.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At the end I managed by creating a filter in the "Map configuration" window (where a map can be imported to the Operations Dashboard). The filter is: "STATE" == "DAMAGED". Then, I created a Summary widget, selecting the "counting" option (rather than "statistics"), and pointing to the filter in the "Source data" voice. That did the trick. Now, whenever I (ideally) go out with the Collector to check the lights and update the "STATE" field from "WORKING" to "DAMAGED", the Operations Dashboards updates the number of lights flagged as "DAMAGED". Below is a sample figure of a situation where 2 lights are flagged as "DAMAGED". I hope this could be of any help for someone who's using Operations Dashboard and is dealing with text filtering.

[image]